# Philips CELP file

Tags: audio, encryption

I got file recorded in Philips speechexec.

I've tried to edit header of this file to open it with different codec but I didn't succeeded. I used Philips CELP codec but I couldn't read it either.

I got information about that this file could be encrypted in SpeechExec transcription software but this application only work with Philips kit.

So is there any other way to decrypt this file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can decrypt this file as Philips is using a proprietary algorithm.